# JSX not allowed in files with extension ' .js' with eslint-config-airbnb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I've installed [eslint-config-airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb) that is supposed to pre configure ESLINT for React:

> Our default export contains all of our ESLint rules, including
>   ECMAScript 6+ and React. It requires eslint, eslint-plugin-import,
>   eslint-plugin-react, and eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y.

My `.eslintrc` extending its configuration:

```
{ "extends": "eslint-config-airbnb",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "mocha": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "new-cap": [2, { "capIsNewExceptions": ["List", "Map", "Set"] }],
    "react/no-multi-comp": 0,
    "import/default": 0,
    "import/no-duplicates": 0,
    "import/named": 0,
    "import/namespace": 0,
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
    "import/no-named-as-default": 2,
    "comma-dangle": 0,  // not sure why airbnb turned this on. gross!
    "indent": [2, 2, {"SwitchCase": 1}],
    "no-console": 0,
    "no-alert": 0,
    "linebreak-style": 0
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react", "import"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/parser": "babel-eslint",
    "import/resolve": {
      "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src"]
    }
  },
  "globals": {
    "__DEVELOPMENT__": true,
    "__CLIENT__": true,
    "__SERVER__": true,
    "__DISABLE_SSR__": true,
    "__DEVTOOLS__": true,
    "socket": true,
    "webpackIsomorphicTools": true
  }
}
```

Unfortunatelly I'm getting the following error when linting a .js file with React JSX code inside it:

```
 error  JSX not allowed in files with extension '.js'              react/jsx-filename-extension
```

Wasn't eslint-config-airbnb configured react to support JSX already, as stated ?

What should be done to remove that error ?

Answer (score 312, accepted):

Either change your file extensions to `.jsx` as mentioned or disable the [jsx-filename-extension](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-filename-extension.md) rule. You can add the following to your config to allow `.js` extensions for JSX.

```
"rules": {
  "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to change your filename extension or disable the rule, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51896943/182875)

Comment: This accepted answer does not disable the rule. It just simply allows .js files to contain JSX and what you've linked seems to create too much chaos in very large scale projects.

Comment: The second "jsx" element in the array is unnecessary. The "js" element is sufficient since the rule already references the "jsx" scope.

Comment: Where is config file ?

Answer (score 31):

It's work for me. hope to help you.

1. disable jsx-filename-extension in `.eslintrc`:

   "rules": {
       "react/jsx-filename-extension": [0]
   }
2. in `webpack.config.js`:

   resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
   },

Comment: gave you the vote for adding the `webpack.config.js` example.

Answer (score 20):

Call me a dummy if it does not work for you

```
    "rules": {
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [0],
        "import/extensions": "off"
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to change your file extension, you can export a function that returns jsx, and then import and call that function in your js file.

```
// greeter.jsx

import React from 'react';

export default name => (
  <div>
    {`Hello, ${name}!`}
  </div>
);
```

and then

```
// index.js

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import greeter from './components/greeter';

const main = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0];

ReactDOM.render(greeter('World'), main);
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  Can somebody explain so I can be a better contributor?

Comment: maybe it's because while this fix "works", it is, at best, a workaround. And including a workaround in multiple JS files throughout your project seems kinda hacky and unprofessional.

Comment: I agree that this technique isn't idiomatic React.  However I have only come across this problem with my entrypoint.  I would not recommend doing this across all files, as it would create awkward code.  If that's your use case, then just modify the linter rules as suggested in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Following [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html):

> Each JSX element is just syntactic sugar for calling React.createElement(component, props, ...children).

Following [Airbnb's style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react):

> Do not use React.createElement **unless you’re initializing the app from a file that is not JSX**.

You could do this:

```
    //index.js
    const app = React.createElement(App);
    ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

To expound on [Martin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3633339/martin-mihaylov) answer, it seems that it is not possible, currently, to use `JSX` in React Native.  [A PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/5233) was created but reverted due to concerns about fragmentation and unknown consequences of having things like `index.ios.jsx`.  I'm not sure how AirBnb works around this or if they do, but I have used basically the same `rules` block as Martin.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers who want to write jsx in `.js` files:

0. Install `npm i react react-dom` even if you *think* you're not writing react.
1. Install `npm i -D @babel/preset-react`
2. In babel config: `plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx']`
3. you should setup `module.rules` for `/\.jsx?$/` files with `babel-loader` (so you will need to install `npm i -D babel-loader` too)

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this problem on VsCode then it might be for **ESLint** this extension, remove **ESLint** this extension to solve this line error issue.