# React Native unable to resolve module X from 'pathToApp.js': could not resolve 'pathToComponentName' as a file nor as a folder

Tags: react-native

My import statement:

```
import Stuff from './components/Stuff';
```

My directory is laid out with explr as the parent directory, the components directory is a direct subdirectory of the parent dir, and App.js, where the import statement is, is in the parent dir.

My 'Stuff.jsx':

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Stuff extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.sidebar} />
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sidebar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 20,
    height: '100%',
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'lightslategrey',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

React Native does not support importing `.jsx` files.  See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46819165/5792003).