# JSX not allowed in files with extension '.tsx'eslint(react/jsx-filename-extension)

Tags: typescript, eslint

In `.tsx` file, why does eslint report:

> JSX not allowed in files with extension '.tsx'eslint(react/jsx-filename-extension)

How can I update the eslint config can resolve this message:

[image]

Comment: Why does your eslint check typescript files, in the first place? AFAIK it won't do it unless explicitly told so.

Comment: try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031126/jsx-not-allowed-in-files-with-extension-js-with-eslint-config-airbnb

Answer (score 127):

You probably want to configure the [react/jsx-filename-extension](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-filename-extension.md) rule in your `.eslintrc.js` so that ESLint is happy about JSX inside your TypeScript files:

```
rules:  {
  'react/jsx-filename-extension': [2, { 'extensions': ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] }],
},
```

Comment: Why is this necessary exactly? I see it here as well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-config-airbnb. Isn't .tsx an obvious filename extension?

Comment: Good point. It's obvious from a TypeScript perspective but they haven't included `.tsx` in default values.

Comment: I believe the first parameter which is `2` refers to a boolean `additionalProperties `and should be `1` (not that it matters here). See: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/lib/rules/jsx-filename-extension.js and other solutions https://stackoverflow.com/a/43031230/1800854

Comment: @MoBeigi: No, `1` means `warning`, `2` means `error`. Both are valid.

Comment: @Remi if you are using airbnb, you need a separate package for typescript support at the moment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript It allows JSX in .tsx files.

Comment: @NachoH I installed eslint-config-airbnb-typescript and then added the following line to my `.eslintrc` file:
`"extends": ["airbnb-typescript", "prettier"],`
but when I run 
`npm run lint` it says Error: Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/dot-notation': You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated.:

Answer (score 46):

Add this rule under the rules section of your eslint configuration:

```
"rules": {
  "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".tsx", ".ts"] }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using `eslint-config-airbnb`. If yes, then at this moment, you need to install a separate package for typescript. Here's the package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript